# How can I show a custom error message in a visualforce page in place of the governor limit

Tags: visualforce, governorlimits

The page has a column called Name which searches account. It is throwing the error Too many query rows: 50001 Error when users we do not search with full name.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, you can't. Governor limit exceptions cannot be caught or handled in any way.

Instead, you must construct your code to avoid firing a limit exception. In this case you appear to be running an unrestricted SOQL query; you should apply a reasonable `LIMIT` clause to that query to prevent a `LimitException` being thrown. Unless you *actually* need 50,000 search results, consider limiting to a much lower value, say a couple of hundred results, to maximize performance for your users while also guarding against limits.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you can't catch errors generated by governor limits. If you want to provide better handling *before* you hit the error violations, you can make use of the [Apex Limits class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) to check for instances where you're getting close to hitting limits. For example, you can make use of the methods `getLimitQueryRows()` and `getQueryRows()` to tell when you're close to hitting the limit for the total number of rows returned in a given transaction. In your case, you'll definitely want to start with David's suggestion of lowering the rows returned per query, but you can use this class to determine how much of the limit remains if you want to use multiple queries to return more results.

Comment: How can we limit query rows in a single transaction when a lot of queries are executed in a normal apex class

Comment: @AritraGosai if you know it's a large query (in terms of row sizes) I'd suggest implementing some logic from the source (Lightning component, Visualforce, etc...) to support [SOQL pagination](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2012/06/the-joys-of-soql-pagination.html) to limit the rows returned per transaction while keeping track of rows you've already covered.